# Put elements at the begginning of an array with filter and sort - javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, filter

I have an array of objects where I want to find certain elements and put them in the beginning or the array. I started doing it by using the find function and it worked but now because there can be more than one element I switch to filter function however, now it stopped working, how can I fix this?

Input example:

```
colors= [
   {name: "green", popular: true},
   {name: "yellow", popular: false},
   {name: "red", popular: true},
   {name: "black", popular: true},
   {name: "red", popular: true}
]
```

Function:

```
sort(colors) {
    let red= colors.filter(color=> colors.name === "red")

    if(red){
        colors.sort(function(x,y){ return x == red? -1 : y == red? 1 : 0; });
    }

    return colors
}
```

Expected Output:

```
colors= [
   {name: "red", popular: true},
   {name: "red", popular: true},
   {name: "green", popular: true},
   {name: "yellow", popular: false},
   {name: "black", popular: true}
]
```

By using filter red variable returns an array instead of an object like with find

Comment: If you just want to get an object the same way you were doing before, why not check that the array has items in it, and if so, take the first element in the array? if(red.length > 0) ...do something with red[0]. If you just want to sort on red, then you can do that without the filter and just use the sort as you are already doing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just sort red parts to top.

```js
const
    colors= [{ name: "green", popular: true }, { name: "yellow", popular: false }, { name: "red", popular: true }, { name: "black", popular: true }, { name: "red", popular: true }];

colors.sort((a, b) => (b.name === "red") - (a.name === "red"));

console.log(colors);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter()` twice and use spread operator to order the arrays correctly

```js
const colors= [
   {name: "green", popular: true},
   {name: "yellow", popular: false},
   {name: "red", popular: true},
   {name: "black", popular: true},
   {name: "red", popular: true}
]

const res = [...colors.filter(x => x.name === "red"), ...colors.filter(x => x.name !== "red")];
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and `unshfit`. Inside reduce call back put all the elements which dont have `red` name and in another array put elements which have red name. The use `unshift` to add the elements at the beginning

```js
let colors = [{
    name: "green",
    popular: true
  },
  {
    name: "yellow",
    popular: false
  },
  {
    name: "red",
    popular: true
  },
  {
    name: "black",
    popular: true
  },
  {
    name: "red",
    popular: true
  }
];

let colArr = [];

let arr = colors.reduce((acc, curr) => {

  if (curr.name === 'red') {
    colArr.push(curr)
  } else {
    acc.push(curr)
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

colArr.forEach((item, index) => {
  arr.unshift(item)
});

console.log(arr)
```